# SQL GROUP BY item, with Price in increments

Tags: sql, dql

I am trying to group a example table bellow by item, with .25 price increments and the sum of qty.

```
| item_id | qoute | qty |  --output table-->  | item_id | qoute | qty |
|---------|-------|-----|                     |---------|-------|-----|
| 10      | 10.99 | 10  |                     | 10      | 10.00 | 20  |
| 10      | 10.00 | 20  |                     | 10      | 10.75 | 10  |
| 10      | 11.00 | 1   |                     | 10      | 11.00 | 1   |
| 10      | 11.27 | 5   |                     | 10      | 11.25 | 10  |
| 10      | 11.33 | 5   |                     | 10      | 11.50 | 10  |
| 10      | 11.50 | 10  |                      

* Notice how the two quotes of 11.27 and 11.33 are grouped together 
  into 11.25 in the output table
```

I don't know if it is possible to do this with SQL or not.  This will ultimately be implemented into Doctrine2 DQL, but I should be able to port any SQL to that easily.

I would really like to do this with SQL.  But if it is not possible, I can probably come up with a way to do it with a algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using the syntax from SQL Server:

```
select item_id, floor(quote * 4.0)/4.0 as roundquote, sum(qty) as qty
from t
group by item_id, floor(quote * 4.0)
order by 1, 2
```

This multiplies the value by 4, truncates to the lower integer, and then divides by 4.  This should round to the nearest $0.25.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/237e0/5)

```
select item_id,
        floor(qoute)
        +(floor(floor((qoute-floor(qoute))*100)/25)*25)/100 
        as quote,
        sum(qty)
        from t
        group by floor(qoute)
        +(floor(floor((qoute-floor(qoute))*100)/25)*25)/100 
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select item_id, floor(quote*4)/4 as quote_band, sum(qty) from your_table group by item_id, round(quote*4)/4
```